# How to do mysql join to get result form 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get category id and name from company category table which do not exists in company category cross table. For example the company with id 3 has already category 1 and category 2 and i want the sql result to get category 3
[image: Company table]

[image: Company category]

[image: Company category cross]

I tried following statement but not getting expected result

```
SELECT `wp_bmg_company_category`.id, `wp_bmg_company_category`.name 
FROM `wp_bmg_company_category` 
INNER JOIN `wp_bmg_company_category_cross` 
ON `wp_bmg_company_category`.id != `wp_bmg_company_category_cross`.categoryid
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understood correctly you search category which is now unused.

1. Select all company data with category ID (return only category ID)
2. Select all data from category where `category id NOT IN (use 1. select data)`

And if you find the only unused category for each company separately. Use something like this (**ADD company_id** for search each company separately, to search unused categories):

```
SELECT *
FROM category ca
WHERE category_id NOT IN
     (SELECT category_id
      FROM category     c1
           JOIN category_cross cc ON c1.id = cc.category_id
      WHERE company_id = 1)
```

Comment: Yes I am searching for unused category. I am not getting you Jan. What query should i use?

Comment: Check my query upper please ;)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an outer join (left or right) that can retrieve all records from a table, regardless whether it is present in the other table. (You may use `not in()` or `not exists()` in place of the outer join).

The other technique you need is called Cartesian join, whereby you match all records from one table with all records from another table. In this case, match all records from the companies table with all records in the categories, to get the complete list of company - category combinations. Then subtract from this the list of categories you have.

```
select co.id, co.name, ca.id, ca.name
from (wp_bmg_company co join wp_bmg_company_category ca) --this creates the Cartesian join
left join wp_bmg_company_category_cross cr on co.id=cr.companyid and ca.id=cr.categoryid
where cr.id is null  --only the non-matched pairs should remain
```

Comment: will this get me unused category by the company?

Comment: Pls make an honest attempt at understanding my answer and trying the code out before asking such a question.